# Better way to run multiple docker commands

Tags: postgresql, bash, docker

I have a docker container for my database. lets call it `my_pgdb`. I am writing a script in which i am issuing multiple commands 1 by 1 i.e.,

```sh
docker exec -i my_pgdb pg_dump --schema-only -U my_user my_db > schema.sql
docker exec -i my_pgdb dropdb -U my_user "${db_name}_my_db" || true
docker exec -i my_pgdb createdb -U my_user "${db_name}_my_db"
cat schema.sql | docker exec -i my_pgdb psql -U my_user "${db_name}_my_db"
```

Is there a better way to merge these commands into 1? I mean i am doing `docker exec` multiple times, can i just issue all commands once or other better optimized way?

Comment: `docker exec -i bash -c 'cmd1 && cmd2 ...'`?

Comment: How would i enter `errors` in that case? also is that the only better way to do so?

Comment: obviously not the only way... i personally use `exec -it -- bash`, then execute anything i like.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **heredoc** in `sh` command like this:

```sh
docker exec -i my_pgdb sh <<-EOF
   pg_dump --schema-only -U my_user my_db > schema.sql
   dropdb -U my_user "${db_name}_my_db" || true
   createdb -U my_user "${db_name}_my_db"
   psql -U my_user "${db_name}_my_db" < schema.sql
EOF
```

Comment: this works great. is there a way to output which command is being executed?

Comment: Yes that can be done. Just add `-x` like `sh -x <<-EOF`